# Using Python module Glom, Extract Irregular Nested Lists into a Flattened List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, data-structures, nested, python-module, glom

Glom makes accessing complex nested data structures easier. 
https://github.com/mahmoud/glom

Given the following toy data structure:

```
target = [
            {
                'user_id': 198,
                'id': 504508,
                'first_name': 'John',
                'last_name': 'Doe',
                'active': True,
                'email_address': 'jd@test.com',
                'new_orders': False,
                'addresses': [
                    {
                        'location': 'home',
                        'address': 300,
                        'street': 'Fulton Rd.'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'user_id': 209,
                'id': 504508,
                'first_name': 'Jane',
                'last_name': 'Doe',
                'active': True,
                'email_address': 'jd@test.com',
                'new_orders': True,
                'addresses': [
                    {
                        'location': 'home',
                        'address': 251,
                        'street': 'Maverick Dr.'
                    },
                    {
                        'location': 'work',
                        'address': 4532,
                        'street':  'Fulton Cir.'
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
```

I am attempting to extract all address fields in the data structure into a flattened list of dictionaries.

```
from glom import glom as glom
from glom import Coalesce
import pprint

"""
Purpose: Test the use of Glom
"""    

# Create Glomspec
spec = [{'address': ('addresses', 'address') }]

# Glom the data
result = glom(target, spec)

# Display
pprint.pprint(result)
```

The above spec provides:

```
[
    {'address': [300]},
    {'address': [251]}
]
```

The desired result is:

```
[
    {'address':300},
    {'address':251},
    {'address':4532}
]
```

#### What Glomspec will generate the desired result?

Comment: I don't know about `glom`, but it looks like what you want is only a single list comprehension away: `[{'address': x['address']} for X in target for x in X['addresses']] `

Comment: @coldspeed I am familiar with list comprehensions and yes, that would work, however, this toy structure is significantly simplified in order to illustrate an issue I am having with the Glom module. Glom appears to have benefits when dealing with very complex structures over list comprehensions. I'm looking for any insight specifically around Glom. Thank you though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of glom 19.1.0 you can use the [`Flatten()` spec](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#glom.Flatten) to succinctly get the results you want:

```py
from glom import glom, Flatten

glom(target,  (['addresses'], Flatten(),  [{'address': 'address'}]))
# [{'address': 300}, {'address': 251}, {'address': 4532}]
```

And that's all there is to it!

You may also want to check out [the convenient flatten() function](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#combining-iterables-with-flatten-and-friends), as well as the powerful [Fold() spec](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#glom.Fold), for all your flattening needs :)

---

Prior to 19.1.0, glom did not have first-class flattening or reduction (as in map-reduce) capabilities. But one workaround would have been to use Python's built-in `sum()` function to flatten the addresses:

```py
>>> from glom import glom, T, Call  # pre-19.1.0 solution
>>> glom(target,  ([('addresses', [T])], Call(sum, args=(T, [])),  [{'address': 'address'}]))
[{'address': 300}, {'address': 251}, {'address': 4532}]
```

Three steps:

1. Traverse the lists, as you had done.
2. Call sum on the resulting list, flattening/reducing it.
3. Filter down the items in the resulting list to only contain the `'address'` key.

Note the usage of [`T`](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#object-oriented-access-and-method-calls-with-t), which represents the current target, sort of like a cursor.

Anyways, no need to do that anymore, in part due to this answer. So, thanks for the great question!

Comment: Thank you, Mahmoud! Hold off on approving answer to see what comes of Sum() and Reduce()!

Comment: @Liquidgenius updated to use the most recent version of glom! :)

Comment: Awesome add to the module! Thanks for all the work on this!

Comment: Could you add an example where you capture a list of dictionaries that also include their respective user_ids? Ie: [{“user_id”:198, “address”: 300},...]

Comment: @Liquidgenius so relative lookups like that are an area we're designing on still, but you can actually do that by assigning to glom's scope, using `S` and `Assign()`:

`glom(target,  ([(Assign(S['user_id'], Spec(T['user_id'])), 'addresses', [{'address': 'address', 'user_id': S['user_id']}]) ], Flatten()))`

And voila, we get: 

`[{'address': 300, 'user_id': 198},
 {'address': 251, 'user_id': 209},
 {'address': 4532, 'user_id': 209}]`

We're losing readability, but it'll work if you simply must have a pure-glom solution :)

Comment: That provides a good use case for normalizing nested data structures. Thanks again!